# How to array child loop in pug nodejs project

Tags: node.js, pug

```
//team  
 const team = {
        title: 'Our dedicated member',
        subTitle: 'Team',
        data: [
            {
                name: "Alax",
                jobTitle: "Developer",
                image: 'frontend/images/3.jpg',
                social: [
                    {
                        name: 'facebook',
                        icon: 'fa-fw.fa.fa-facebook',
                        link: 'http://www.facebook.com'
                    },
                    {
                        name: 'twitter',
                        icon: 'fa-fw.fa.fa-twitter',
                        link: 'http://www.twitter.com'
                    },
                    {
                        name: 'linkedin',
                        icon: 'fa-fw.fa.fa-linkedin',
                        link: 'http://www.linkedin.com'
                    },
                    {
                        name: 'dribbble',
                        icon: 'fa-fw.fa.fa-dribbble',
                        link: 'http://www.dribbble.com'
                    }
                ]
            },
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
```

I expect the output social name, link, icon

Full will be E.I

Name: Alax,
Title: Developer,
Image: Image,
social: 
  Facebook,
  Twitter,
  Linkedin,
  Dribbble

Name: Jon
Title: Marketing
Image: Image
social: 
  Facebook,
  Dribbble

Comment: this problem has been solved

Comment: If the problem has been solved, please add an answer to the question so we can all learn from it. Thanks!